# Python finding time to return to equilibrium in SHM

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a model `y` which models the motion of simple harmonic motion (SHM) of say, a pendulum. I want to be able to find the time `t` in which the pendulum returns to its rest position (at `y=d`) after it has been displaced.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

A = 10                      # amplitude
w = 3                       # frequency
t = np.linspace(0,100,100)  # time (arb. units)
b = -0.5                    # phase
c = 0.1                     # decay rate
d = 20                      # equilibrium

y = A * np.sin(w*t+b) * np.exp(-c*t) + d

plt.figure()
plt.plot(t,y,'-')

plt.show()
```

How do I find where the `y` array has many consecutive `y=d` values and identify the corresponding `t` where the first `y=d` occurs? Or is there a much simpler method of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`y` never returns to *exactly* `d` but rather keeps oscillating around it in smaller and smaller amounts. You can see this by graphing `y[50:]` for instance. You could make `t` longer and longer and still see the same behavior, until floating-point math errors kick in and round the value to `d`. This is because `exp` tends to 0 but doesn't actually reach 0.

In a physical system, static friction kicks in at sufficiently small velocities and brings things to a halt, but this isn't modeled in the equation for `y`.

Depending on your purposes, it's probably enough to ask "when is `y` smaller than some distance away from `d`". Say you have a small number `delta = d*0.001`. You can see where `y` is less than `delta` away from `d` by calculating:

```
dist = np.abs(y-d)
```

Since you know `y` is monotonically getting closer to `d`, you can look from the end of the array back to the beginning to find when it first exceeds the target distance:

```
close = np.flipud(dist) < delta # flipud time reverses dist, close is True where we are close to d
idx = np.where(close == False)[0][0] # find index of first time we were not close
tValue = np.flipud(t)[idx] # find corresponding value of t
```

There is a big assumption here, that `t` was sufficiently long to allow the oscillation to decay below `delta` away from `d`. Note also that you can't search from the beginning to the first time `y` gets close to `d`, because you might oscillate away again. You can demonstrate this by setting `t = np.linspace(0, 100, 1000)` for instance to more densely sample `y`.